# `ERR Syntax error, try CLIENT (LIST | KILL ip:port)` redis server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob, redis-server

`ERR Syntax error, try CLIENT (LIST | KILL ip:port)` error shows up when running an active job, I have tried several solutions but still getting the same error.

controller.rb

```
AutoMailerJob.set(wait_until: 1.minute).perform_later(project)
```

gemfile

`gem 'sidekiq'`

i have tried the version downgrading the redis from v4 to v3.3.3 like [this](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4272#issuecomment-435150068) but still the same error.
Any one have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Sidekiq is 5.2.7.  Please upgrade.

Comment: Mike do you know of any issues with Sidekiq on Windows Subsystem Linux?  We are getting this error when we try to enqueue a job or run a worker process, but we have 5.2.7 and Redis 5.0.5 installed.  The same setup works fine on macOS.

Comment: I need a full backtrace to help.